# How to import a JSON file to PostgreSQL database in BASH

Tags: json, bash, postgresql

I'm working on a bash script and I need to import a JSON file into my Postgres database. This JSON file is really big and I have tried diferents ways but all of this didn´t work.
I can´t post a example of the JSON file because it is really big (like 15Mb)

Using a bash variable to store the data:

```
VAR=$(cat cucumber.json.1)
su -c "psql -A -t -d tareas -c \"insert into consulta (url, identificador, fecha, artefacto) values ('UNKNOWN', $identificadorBBDD, '$diaBBDD', :'$VAR')\"" postgres
```

It returns that the list of the arguments is too long, I think is because when is reading the variable, the command thinks that the variable just finish and it breaks the structure of the query.

I tried to use the function in postgres lo_import but I got the same result.

I used a postgres command to store the data but it didn´t work:

```
\set content `cat cucumber.json.1` create temp table t ( j json); insert into t values(:'content');
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `Copy` to load the json(multiline) into a temp table as rows and then update your json column in the main table with the json from the temp table, concatenated correctly.

Comment: Thank you to your idea but i found another way to solve the problem. You can check it in the answer of the cuestion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Finally i can solve using the next code into my .sh

> VAR=$(cat cucumber.json.1)
>
> psql postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/tareas << EOF
>
> insert into consulta (url, identificador, fecha ,artefacto) values ('UNKNOWN',
> ident, 'date', '$VAR');
>
> EOF

I don´t know why it doesn´t give me the same error as before but in this way, the query works and it imports the json file to the database.